Is there a simple description of the total space of a principal S^1 bundle over a compact surface?
It is known that principal $S^1$-bundles over a compact surface $\Sigma_g$ are classified by their Chern classes in $H^2(\Sigma_g, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.
When the Chern number is zero, the bundle is trivial, and the total space is diffeomorphic to $\Sigma_g \times S^1$. When the Chern number is one, and $g=0$, the total space is diffeomorphic to $S^3$.
I wonder if there are other cases where the total space has a nice topological description. For instance, what is the total space of the principal $S^1$-bundle over the torus, with Chern number 1?
I can construct these fibrations by hand by removing a disc from the surface, taking trivial bundles over the two parts, and gluing them back together with the gluing map determining the Chern number. Still, even for the Hopf fibration it's not clear that the total space is $S^3$ by looking from that point of view.

The unit tangent bundle of $\Sigma_g$ is a principal $S^1$ bundle (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/181710/the-unit-tangent-bundle-of-2-or-4-manifolds-as-a-principal-s1-or-s3) and has Chern number $\chi(\Sigma_g) = 2 - 2g$

You can describe this particular manifold as the mapping torus of a  Dehn twist on $T^2$. Or as the quotient of the 3-dimensional real Heisenberg group by the integer Heisenberg subgroup. Whether you will find this description "simple" is up to you to decide.

The mapping torus description is very nice IMO for this particular case.
